# Can json-api fetch posts by their slug after the post name has changed?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-json-api

Using https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/ in an environment that segregates the standard wordpress install from a site that effectively uses wordpress as a service.

---

Site A http://example.com (the consumer)

Site B http://wordpress.example.com (the standard wordpress site with the json-api plugin installed)

---

Old slug: **test-article**
New slug: **test-article-new**

---

Site A consumes site B via the JSON_API_Query::get method

So a call might look like: http://wordpress.example.com/api/post/get_post/?slug=test-article

But this will return no results because the slug is now **test-article-new**

However, a http call to bog-standard wordpress i.e. http://wordpress.mysite.com/**test-article** will correctly 301 to http://wordpress.mysite.com/**test-article-new**

Is the ability to follow old permalinks/canonical URLs available in the json-api plugin?

If not, how can this functionality be mimicked in the API controllers?